# EVTOL(Electrical vertical takeoff and landing) aircraft holding pattern

Tags: holding

There is a specific holding pattern and procedures for fixed winged aircraft.Is there any specific holding pattern for EVTOL ? as they have capability to hold a position and altitude .

Comment: Wouldn’t any VTOL aircraft follow the same rules and regulations as helicopters regardless of their power source? My understanding is that helicopters use the same holding patterns as fixed wing aircraft. It’s their traffic patterns, IFR minimums, safe altitude minimums, and distance from persons and property that are different.

Comment: Hovering takes a lot more power than flying a racetrack pattern.  Besides, how many EVTOL aircraft are actually sharing the airspace with standard fixed wing and helicopters?

Comment: Although, some metropolitan areas have specific IFR charts for helicopters, the DFW Helicopter IFR chart I reviewed via ForeFlight shows no specific routes nor holding patterns. Since this chart is for a terminal area, I would assume all Enroute travel would be governed by the common VFR sectionals and IFR High, Low, and Planning charts.

Comment: Last year, EASA was developing the framework for rules for small VTOL aircraft. https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/stories/easa-releases-framework-for-vtol-operation.html   I don’t believe it has been finalized. Nor is it expanded worldwide or through ICAO yet. There probably is no rush on the regulation process considering the small number of VTOL aircraft outside of the rotorcraft or ultralight category that are not military at this time. And, the military plays by its own set of rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Helicopters can be put in "racetrack" style holds just like fixed wing aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44682/do-helicopters-fly-holding-patterns-under-ifr), COPTER [approaches even include them](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2003/00289COPTERIL13.PDF). There is no reason to believe if/when VTOL aircraft become more prevalent this will be any different.

[Hovering is inefficient and difficult](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73857/can-all-helicopters-hover-and-how-long-does-it-take-to-stop) which can be made even more complicated when in IMC making it not ideal for a holding maneuver which is often issued to either kill time or allow a pilot time to pull up a new plate or get set up for a new approach.